# Samsung gts7562 not showing in device dropdown of visual studio 2013 for Xamarin Android app Testing

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to connect my android phone Samsung GT-S7562 to visual studio 2013 via usb cable and want to load my Xamaring android app (test app) on this device. But the device not shown in device dropdown list of VS. USB debugging option has been enabled in device.

Data is being successfully transferred via USB cable but can't be able to load app on this device.

The device also not showing in Xamarin Sudio device dropdown list.

How can I fix this problem and what configuration are required to attach my device to VS.

Thanks

Comment: First step would be to check what adb is saying, i.e. adb devices.

Answer (score 0):

Did you [authorize your computer](http://www.phonearena.com/news/How-to-enable-USB-debugging-on-Android_id53909) to debug?

Comment: Thanks Miha Miarkic, Yes I have enabled the USB debugging option. While enabling this option device does not show "Allow this computer bla bla " type checkbox to configure this option. It just enable USB debugging option and show pop-up info what this option do. So I think I still not allow to connect computer to device.